# Parse custom binary protocol from inputstream

Tags: java, binary, protocols

I have a couple of questions regarding a custom binary protocol.

Our server is connected to a CCT (Custom Command Terminal) which is controlled by the user and can send binary commands to this central unit. The communication between the CCT and the server is a standard ethernet socket on a certain port.

All commands and messages in both directions will use the same frame format:

- **STX**: 0x02 - byte indicating the start of the command
- **Length**: The length of the messages including the STX and length bytes but not the checksum byte
- **Command**: The type of command
- **Parameter 1-n**: the data bytes for the given command number
- **ChkSm**: A checksum byte

When the server receives a message with a valid checksum or a first connection, it will send a single acknowledge byte back.

For the communication, I'm using a standard Java socket with a DataInputStream and DataOutputStream.

1. How I can correctly read in the bytes from the DataInputStream and cast these back to their original values (integer, booleans, ...). I know there are the `readByte()`, `readShort()` and `readbyte(byteArr, offsett, length)` methods but why would I prefer the one over the other.
2. `readbyte(byteArr, offsett, length)` returns the number of bytes read. Why would I use this value is my scenario. What size should the byteArr be as my parameter?

   ```
    byte[] responseBytes = new byte[5];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    try {
        bytesRead = mInputStream.read(responseBytes, 0, 4);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
   ```
3. When I receive data from the inputstream and I use `readByte()`, would this be the STX (the start of the command)?
4. How are binary protocols handled? Is there any best practice on getting started on this? Maybe an example based on what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: What is value of "single acknowledge byte"?

Comment: The value is: 0x0A

Answer (score 1):

> How I can correctly read in the bytes from the DataInputStream

Don't use `DataInputStream`. Just use the plain `InputStream`.

> `readbyte(byteArr, offsett, length)` returns the number of bytes read. Why would I use this value is my scenario. What size should the byteArr be as my parameter?

Since the `Length` is only a single byte, a command can be at most 256 bytes long (255 + 1 byte `ChkSm`), so use a `byte[256]`.

The value returned by `read(responseBytes)` then tells you how many bytes you actually received, so you know whether you got all the bytes (compare with `Length`).

> When I receive data from the inputstream and I use `readByte()`

You probably wouldn't use `read()` to read a single byte, only `read(responseBytes)`.

> How are binary protocols handled?

Depends on the protocol. There is no single good answer.